# space that maps time to continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am learning the space that maps time into Banach spaces and I have the following confusion.

Let $X=C_b([0,T]\times \mathbb{R})$ be the space of bounded continuous function $f(t,x)$, where the continuity is defined pointwisely as usual. However, we can also consider the space 
$Y=C([0,T];C_b(\mathbb{R}))$, which contains functions $v(t,x)$ such that 
$$v(t,\cdot)\in C_b(\mathbb{R}),\quad t\in[0,T],$$
and $$\lim_{t\to t_0}\|v(t,\cdot)-v(t_0,\cdot)\|_\infty=0,\quad \forall t_0\in [0,T].$$

I am wondering whether these two spaces are the same or has any relation. Clearly, if $v\in X$, the requirement for $Y$ is well-defined. Also if $v\in Y$, since by definition, the supnorm is continuous in $t$, $|v(t,x)|\le M<\infty$  for all $(t,x)\in [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}$.